# Moment.js formatted time incorrect

Tags: javascript, time, momentjs

I'am using [moment.js](https://momentjs.com) for formatting date, time and duration.

From api I get e.g. this string `"1540034040"`. It should be converted to 13:14

In my React app I have a function which returns `return moment(time, 'HH:mm').format('HH:mm');`, but then I get another time `15:40`? I see there is a package moment [timezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone/). But I don't want to install another package.

Is there somehow a way to fix this with just moment or javascript, without installing another package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working by:
first transform my string to a number so I am able to use `unix()` and then format with `moment().format()`

```
const timeString = time;
const timeNumber = parseInt(timeString, 10);
return moment.unix(timeNumber).format('HH:mm');
```

Answer (score 0):

The time string you are passing ("1540034040") is having 10 digit long. the moment package is expecting this kind of string in millisecond format( 13 digit long string ).
For example "1540034040000".

For this given string the time will get converting to some other past date with different time because you have passed second instead of milliseconds.

For debugging you should try to print whole date and time of the given string ("1540034040") instead of just hours and minutes. it will make things more clear.

You should try passing the milliseconds. i am sure it will fix the issue.